# Python - Pandas Dataframe with Multiple Names per Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way in pandas to give the same column of a pandas dataframe two names, so that I can index the column by only one of the two names? Here is a quick example illustrating my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

index=['a','b','c','d']
# The list of tuples here is really just to 
# somehow visualize my problem below: 
columns = [('A','B'), ('C','D'),('E','F')]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

# I can index like that:
df[('A','B')]
# But I would like to be able to index like this:
df[('A',*)] #error
df[(*,'B')] #error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a multi-index column:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

Then you can do:

```
df.loc[:, ("A", slice(None))]
```

[image]

Or: `df.loc[:, (slice(None), "B")]`

Here `slice(None)` is equivalent to selecting all indices at the level, so `(slice(None), "B")` selects columns whose second level is `B` regardless of the first level names. This is semantically the same as `:`. Or write in pandas index slice way. `df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, "B"]]` for the second case.

Comment: Thx, that does the job. Could you please leave s short sentence about the slice(None)?